# Zustand state consistency and timing during an event

Tags: javascript, zustand

Ok, here's a puzzler.  I have a select input and I'm using Zustand for state.  I'm seeing inconsistent state and not getting something I suspect.

It looks like this.

```
const handleSortChange = async (event) => {
  // set a state variable
  setSort(event.value)

  // do a network call using sortBy and other things
  // the call is wrong when using sortBy and I'll replace
  // this bug with console.log statements below ...
}
```

There are two values for the select: "one" and "two".

If I console.log this stuff out, I see the problem and the bug.  I can't use the state variable inside of this function.  It doesn't await, resolve or behave the way I think it will.

So for my select, if I flip between one and two, I get this funny behavior:

```
const handleSortChange = async (event) => {
  // set a state variable
  setSort(event.value)  // this sets sortBy
  console.log(event.value)
  console.log(sortBy)   // this is the zustand state variable that is in scope
  // I expect these would be the same, but they aren't!  :O
}
```

The console.log output looks like this when switching from "one" to "two" on the select input.

```
two  // event.value
one  // the in-scope zustand variable sortBy as a read after the set
```

When switching to "two" on the select, I get the opposite but these variables aren't the same?

```
one  // event.value
two  // the set variable sortBy
```

When switching to "one" on the select.  Because something isn't consistent or resolving like I think it is.

I thought that the zustand state variable would be consistent (especially when I add await and eslint is telling me that await does have effect for this function).  This isn't an issue for me right now because I can use the parameter for everything I need.  But I just feel like I'm missing something big here and I hope that Zustand isn't going to gotcha me when I need to rely on a state change or consistent store somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the same issue and behavior that React has with `setState`.  With `setState` in React you wouldn't do this even though this is a common trap.  The value is not updated immediately, this way of thinking does not work for a concurrent GUI.

https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1389376376508227592

In the case of Zustand, it might not even have a callback function to fire after `set` is called.  In other words, this isn't going to work at this time.